# Securing a Google App Engine service deployed in Node/Java against a scripting attack

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app engine service deployed in GAE (written in Node) to accept a series of click stream events from my website. The data is pushed as an CORS ajax call. I think, since the POST request can be seen in browser through the developer tools, somebody can use the app engine URL to post similar data from the browser console.( like in firefox, we can resend the URL. Chrome also has this features i guess)
A few options I see here is,

1. Use the firewall setting to allow only my domain to send data to the GAE. 
            This can still fail me since the requests can be made from the browser console repetitively)
2. Use a WAF ( Web Application Firewall) as a proxy to create some custom rule.

What should be my approach to secure my GAE service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the #1 approach would actually work for you: if the post requests are visible in the browser's development tools it means they're actually made by the client, not by your website, so you can't actually use firewall rules to secure them.

Since requests are coming into the service after fundamentally originating on your own website/app (where I imagine the clicks in the mentioned sequences happen) I'd place the sanity check inside that website/app (where you already have a lot more context info available to make decisions) rather than in the service itself (where, at best, you'd have to go through loops to discover/restore the original context required to make intelligent decisions). Of course, this assumes that the website/app is not a static/dumb site and has some level of intelligence.

For example, for the case using browser development tools for replaying post requests you described - the website app could have some 'executed' flag attached to the respective request, set on the first invocation (when the external service is also triggered) and could thus simply reject any subsequent cloned/copy of the request.

With the above in place I'd then replace sending the service request from the client. Instead I'd use your website/app to create and make the service request instead, after passing through the above-mentioned sanity checks. This is almost trivial to secure with simple firewall rules - valid requests can only come in from your website/app, not from the clients. I suspect this is closer to what you had in mind when you listed the #1 approach.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am working out on different possible solutions right now. Will consider these suggestions and will let you know my approach. Thanks for the quick response (Y)